# Duplicate when populating NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am trying to add two objects to my array but when i inspect the array, the second object appears in the list twice. Does anyone know why?

```
list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];

// Create person 1
person.name = @"Fred";
person.gender = @"unknown";

// Append to array
[list addObject:person];
[person release];

// Create person 2
person.name = @"Bob";
person.gender = @"male";

// Append to array again
[list addObject:person];
[person release];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not creating two person instances, but just one.

Either do this:

```
list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
Person *person;

// Create person 1
person = [[Person alloc] init];
person.name = @"Fred";
person.gender = @"unknown";

// Append to array
[list addObject:person];
[person release];

// Create person 2
person = [[Person alloc] init]; //this line right here!
person.name = @"Bob";
person.gender = @"male";

// Append to array again
[list addObject:person];
[person release];
```

or assign a second person to a second variable.

The `person` variable still points to the first person instance. You need to change the variable to a new instance, otherwise you're simply inserting the person twice and also overwriting its properties.

Comment: I originally did this, but you get the error `Redefinition of 'person'`

Comment: You probably forgot to remove the `Person *` for the second line.

Comment: The `Person *` part is the definition. The `person = …;` part is the assignment. You can either combine them into one expression or split them up (as I did. Not necessary though, just clearer, imho).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the array does not make a copy of the object you passed to it to add, instead it only holds a reference to the object. So what you're doing is creating an object, assigning to its properties, giving a reference to the array, mutating the same object, and then adding the same (but mutated) object to the array again.

You need to make a new Person object each time instead of mutating the same object.

Answer (score 2):

You've only created one person. Try this:

```
list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];

// Create person 1
person.name = @"Fred";
person.gender = @"unknown";

// Append to array
[list addObject:person];
[person release];

// Create person 2
Person *person2 = [[Person alloc] init];
person2.name = @"Bob";
person2.gender = @"male";

// Append to array again
[list addObject:person2];
[person release];
```

The issue here is that when you added the first person to the array, and then modified the original object, the object is also modified in the array --- you need to instantiate a new version of the "person" object and modify it.

If you want to create many, many people, I suggest using a `for` loop:

```
NSArray *names = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Fred", @"Bob"];
NSArray *genders = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"unknown", @"male"];

for (int i = 0; i<[names count]; i++) {
    Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];
    person.name = [names objectAtIndex:i];
    person.gender = [genders objectAtIndex:i];
    [list addObject:person];
    [person release];
}
```

Comment: This works, but how would you re-use (re-initialise) the person variable so you don't have to create different `Person` variables?